# Apache rewriterule assistance needed

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove query string: ?id= from this URL:

https://example.com/news-and-events/news/?id=/nodle/nodle-io/ledger-integration-update-compatibility-status-236699676dc6

and keep the page loading/working fine

I tried this:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?id=(.*)?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ $1%2? [R=301,L]

it seems to strip the ?id= out fine but the page won't load, just 404s.

My issue is making the content load / carry over on the new URL.

https://example.com/news-and-events/news/nodle/nodle-io/ledger-integration-update-compatibility-status-236699676dc6

Any help appreciated,
Thanks
Rob

Was expecting URL to load fine and not 404, but with the shorter URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

The `/` is missing because you probably have not declared the `RewriteBase`. As you are using the whole `REQUEST_URI` this one below in the code should do it.

Additionally the second bracket expression of the `RewriteCond` needs an `*` to provide the full `QUERY_STRING` (reduced by the search pattern `id=/`).

File: `/news-and-events/news/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/news-and-events/news/"

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.)?id=/(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ $1%2? [R=301,L]
```

---

**Simplyfied Version**

File: `/news-and-events/news/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /news-and-events/news/
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^id=/(.*)" [NC]
RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1%1?" [R=301,L]
```

**OR** within your `virtualhost.conf`-file:

Here the context is essential:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/"
    # Other directives
    
    # Only required once:
    RewriteEngine On
        
    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/news-and-events/news/">
        RewriteBase "/news-and-events/news/"
        RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "^id=/(.*)" [NC]
        RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1%1?" [R=301,L]
    </Directory>
    
    # More <Directory> container
    
</VirtualHost>
```

BTW: It is a good habit to enclose the patterns in double quotes, even if not always necessary.

**Some Comments**

You match against `QUERY_STRING`:

```
QUERY_STRING = 'id=/nodle/nodle-io/ledger-integration-update-compatibility-status-236699676dc6'
```

It will always begin with the character *after* the `?` in the URL.
So the match in the `RewriteCond` does not

As the regex is greedy and you select the whole string forcing the `^` start and `$`stop of the string is obsolete. Also making it optional by `?` is unnecessary, as `(.*)` may evaluate to empty by itself.

**Notes**

- Meanwhile you've disclosed, that the code shall reside in a `virtualhost.conf`-file of the apache server.
- Also the configuration is not standalone but a sub-directory of a Wordpress installation, that also uses some Rewrite rules.
  As you have enabled the directive for `.htaccess`, but want to write the rules in the `virtualhost.conf`-file.
- Using the propper  container is essential to prohibit cross-influences with your Wordpress installation (in both directions).

```
AllowOverride All
```

*you should first cleanup all possibly still existing previous "experiments" within `.htaccess` files to solve your problem.
— Really important!*

---

But obviously your intent has been the inverse of that what has been your question:

- [Apache hide query string in URL but keep URL working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759598/apache-hide-query-string-in-url-but-keep-url-working)
- [Php to remove query string in URL but keep URL working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765914/php-to-remove-query-string-in-url-but-keep-url-working)

*So besides the fact, the presented solution does what you've asked, there is obviously no content at the rewritten URL and you end up with a `404 · Not found`.* HTML client error.

Doing something like this has its sense, when it comes to a changed URI-structure (i.e. because of a change of the serving software) and you want your visitors to be able to follow the content. Also by the HTML status code `301 · Moved permanently` the search engines will quickly learn to use the new URI logic and keep the SEO up.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried 1) but it does the same as before, the rule works but it 404s, I need it to some how keep the page but make URL pretty

Comment: it gives an error AH00526: Syntax error on line 29 of /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf:
RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files  please seee my conf http://pastie.org/p/5wUNoBqAlBhDawuqQgIFLh

Comment: Thanks for the copy of the code. I had the impression you are using the rewrite code in the `.htaccess` file.  — The order of rewrite `rules` is essential. Also they are concurring with your rewrite rules for WordPress.

Comment: Do all of the URLs you want to rewrite point into the "news"-folder? `https://example.com/news-and-events/news/`

Comment: Ah sorry no by default .htaccess is disabled so I have to use .conf file. the part after /?id=/ can be anything as there are hundreds of URLs. The part before will always be website.com/news-and-events/news/ or website.com/news-and-events/event/

Comment: These "news"-URLs are not part of your WordPress installation?

Comment: it's a custom php page within wordpress

Comment: As wordpress does not seem to put its bits to this, I've set the news rewrite rules in front of the wordpress rewirtes. http://pastie.org/p/1GPuuzsy2Na6eb7WnlOLFm

Comment: Is it possible to setup a call? do you have a consulting website? There is no Directory /opt/bitnami/wordpress/news-and-events/news on the server.  Happy to pay for your time. thanks.

Comment: just exchange the path. You should have the written `./news-and-events/news/` path somewhere. – Just compare the public sample here with the path in the conf-file and you should be able to replace.

Comment: It does not work any longer, still have id in URL, let me know how I can reach you. thanks.

Comment: Telegram or Threema?