# Apache hide query string in URL but keep URL working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two types of URLs, but they can have anything after the query string as we have 1000's of URLs/posts.

Both have /?id=/ in them, I wish to hide that/remove it but for the page to still load.

These pages are custom slugs in wordpress, and I don't have .htaccess enabled in Apache 2.4 so it would need to be done via .conf rules

Can anyone help? the two URL types are:

https://example.com/news-and-events/news/?id=/kanpai-pandas/@KanpaiPandas/the-largest-airdrop-competition-in-web3-dd6f8f78c758

and

https://examples.com/news-and-events/event/?id=/e/crypto-for-lawyers-in-60-minutes-watch-on-demand-tickets-363441371927

WordPress install root is in /news-and-events/

I can get the query string removed but the result is a 404, not the original content/page, which does not seem to work.

Thank you
Rob

Code I have so far:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?id=(.*)?$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ $1%2? [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this within your <VirtualHost *:80> container:

```
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/news-and-events/news/">

    RewriteBase "/news-and-events/news/"
    RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" ""
    RewriteRule "(.*)" "index.php?id=/$1" [L]

</Directory>
```

Alternatively it can be used in an `.htaccess` file:

File: `/news-and-events/news/.htaccess`

```
RewriteBase "/news-and-events/news/"
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" ""
RewriteRule "(.*)" "index.php?id=/$1" [L]
```

*Using rewrite rules in the appropriate path they are designed for is essential to achieve the desired functionality.*

#### How it works

Using **the right directory** for the rules prohibits that the rules are tested against other paths, possibly destroying the request-URI leading to them. Also the rules are only called for relevant requests, saving processing time.

The **RewriteBase** defines what is "local". Up to this point the path will be cropped for further processing. The Log:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/vhosts/myhost/htdoc/news-and-events/news/
applying pattern '.*' to uri ''
```

*Be sure to include the final `/`. – Else you will get problems!*

By the **RewriteCond** we test only if a `QUERY_STRING` exists (thats everything after the `?` in the web address. — In the szenario of this question it must not exist, but will exist after processing. — This will prohibit a positive match of the URI after it has been rewritten and will pass the rewrite filter the second time.

The **RewriteRule** glues the missing part to generate a URI with `?id=/` the "localized" URI. When the rewrite step is finished the global part of the URI will be prepended to the new full REQUEST_URI.

Instead of inserting `index.php?id=/` using only `?id=/` would have been enough to fulfill the job, but by adding the answer of apache's next step *"What is the right index file?"* saves a few steps of processing the request, speeding up the things.

Using `[L]`(Leave the rewrite rules) instead of [R=301,L] (resource moved permanently, leave) will prevent that the search engines will learn the new URI and it also prohibits that the rewritten URI is shown in the address bar. Internally this is a 302 (temporary redirect). The Log:

```
redirect to http://example.com/news-and-events/news/index.php?id=/kanp...8c758 [REDIRECT/302]
```

#### Requires a counterpart

The task is to "prettify the address". So the PHP script, that generates the URIs has to change its behavior to issue the prettified URIs the visitors and search engines should see and click.

Somewhere in the php-script the processing for the URL-generation results in something like

```
<?php
// ....
news_path = "/news-and-events/news/";
news_uri = "/kanpa...8c758";

final_news_link = $news_path . "id=" . $news_uri;
?>
```

The assembling of the `final_news_link` has to be changed to

```
final_news_link = $news_path . $news_uri;
```

so the prettified address will be published.

Comment: @Rob Please also have a look at your other request for additional details: "Apache rewriterule assistance needed" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743965/apache-rewriterule-assistance-needed/75744193#75744193 – Finally it would have been better to write all as one task and that in a well documented manner.