# Php to remove query string in URL but keep URL working

Tags: wordpress, url, mod-rewrite

I have two types of URLs, but they can have anything after the query string as we have 1000's of URLs/posts.

Both have /?id=/ in them, I wish to hide that/remove it but for the page to still load.

These pages are custom slugs in wordpress, and I don't have .htaccess enabled in Apache 2.4 so I've done some rewrite rules in Apache conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?id=(.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ $1%2? [R=301,L]
```

But the pages now 404 so I think I need to do something with the php pages too? or can I do the whole thing in php?

Can anyone help? the two URL types are:

```
https://example.com/news-and-events/news/?id=/kanpai-pandas/@KanpaiPandas/the-largest-airdrop-competition-in-web3-dd6f8f78c758
```

and

```
https://example.com/news-and-events/event/?id=/e/crypto-for-lawyers-in-60-minutes-watch-on-demand-tickets-363441371927
```

WordPress install root is in /news-and-events/

I can get the query string removed but the result is a 404, not the original content/page, which does not seem to work.

Tried apache rules but not php

Comment: For what it's worth, WordPress's permalinks implementation critically depends on its ability to write into the `.htaccess` file and for your web server to use it.

Comment: We can do the rules by calling a .conf file in Apache, so it's basically the same, the site works fine, the issue is as above. thanks.

Comment: Hi Rob, as I meanwhile know your demand, please note that what you need is a change of the code that issues the URLs containing the string `?id=`. This code has to be changed to issue your "pretty" URLs structured like a directory path. — By the rewrite code I've provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759598/apache-hide-query-string-in-url-but-keep-url-working/75777893#75777893 the final result should be fine. — With these information here, none can help you. Please see also the answer at your first request   (ID: 75744193)